# Configuring Kafka Client Producer with PEM file

Tags: apache-kafka, producer

We have Kafka server which is implemented in GO language. We got below information from server team. We are using Kafka Java sdk for connecting to server. I don't know what properties to be used in "producer.Properties" in order to connect to Kafka server which is implemented in GO language using PEM file. Could someone please help me?

ca-cert

bootstrap details

username

password

topic name

Answer (score 1):

I have identified the solution. Here are the steps I have followed.

Producer.properties file:

```
bootstrap.servers=brokerinformation:9094
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
ssl.truststore.type = PEM
ssl.truststore.location = /home/cacert.pem
```

Client Jaas file configuration:

```
KafkaClient 
{

     org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required

     username="username"

     password="password";

};
```

Export the jaas configuration file path:

```
export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=Jaas config file path"
```

Run the producer command:

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server "brokerinformation:9094" --topic "topic_name" --producer.config="path to producer config file"
```

That's it. I am able to connect to broker using SASL authentication using PEM file.

I have followed the **second point** in below article.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/11.0.0?topic=messages-authenticating-connections-kafka-cluster-by-using-saslscram